# I altered my PHP code, but the result shown in the browser does not change. Is there some sort of "cache" bug in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm studying AJAX these days, here is my html code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Rob's Rock 'n' Roll Memorabilia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/thumbnails.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="images/logotypeLeft.png" alt="Rob's Rock 'n' Roll Memorabilia"
         width="394" height="91" id="logotypeLeft"/>
    <img src="images/logotypeRight.png" alt="Rob's Rock 'n' Roll Memorabilia"
         width="415" height="92" id="logotypeRight"/>

    <div id="introPane">
        <p>Are you looking for the perfect gift for the rock fan in your life?
            Maybe you want a guitar with some history behind it, or a conversation
            piece for your next big shindig. Look no further! Here you'll find all
            sorts of great memorabilia from the golden age of rock and roll.</p>

        <p><strong>Click on an image to the left for more details.</strong></p>
    </div>

    <div id="thumbnailPane">
        <img src="images/itemGuitar.jpg" width="301" height="105" alt="guitar"
             title="itemGuitar" id="itemGuitar"/>
        <img src="images/itemShades.jpg" alt="sunglasses" width="301" height="88"
             title="itemShades" id="itemShades"/>
        <img src="images/itemCowbell.jpg" alt="cowbell" width="301" height="126"
             title="itemCowbell" id="itemCowbell"/>
        <img src="images/itemHat.jpg" alt="hat" width="300" height="152"
             title="itemHat" id="itemHat"/>
    </div>

    <div id="detailsPane">
        <img src="images/blank-detail.jpg" width="346" height="153" id="itemDetail"/>
        <div id="description"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my **thumbnails.js**:

```
/**
 * Created by Czyhandsome on 2015/10/20.
 */
window.onload = initPage;
var request = createRequest();

function initPage() {
    var thumbs = document.getElementById("thumbnailPane").getElementsByTagName("img");

    for (var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; ++i) {
        var image = thumbs[i];
        image.onclick = function () {
            var detailUrl = "images/" + this.title + "-detail.jpg";
            document.getElementById("itemDetail").src = detailUrl;
            getDetails(this.title);
        };
    }
}

function getDetails(itemName) {
    if (request == null) {
        alert("Unable to create request.");
        return;
    }
    var url = "getDetails.php?ImageID=" + encodeURIComponent(itemName);
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails;
    request.send(null);
}

function displayDetails() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            var detailDiv = document.getElementById("description");
            detailDiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
}


function createRequest() {
    var request;
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (tryMs) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (otherMS) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (failed) {
                request = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return request;
}
```

Here is my **getDetail.php**:

```
<?php

$details = array (
    'itemGuitar'    =>  "<p>Pete Townshend once played this guitar while his own axe was in the shop having bits of drumkit removed from it.</p>",
    'itemShades'    =>  "<p>Yoko Ono's sunglasses. While perhaps not valued much by Beatles fans, this pair is rumored to have been licked by John Lennon.</p>",
    'itemCowbell'   =>  "<p>Remember the famous \"more cowbell\" skit from Saturday Night Live? Well, this is the actual cowbell.</p>",
    'itemHat'       =>  "<p>Michael Jackson's hat, as worn in the \"Billie Jean\" video. Not really rock memorabilia, but it smells better than Slash's tophat.</p>"
);

echo $details[$_REQUEST['ImageID']];

?>
```

But when I read this page, it appeared like this:
[bug.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/benfp.png)

After I deleted the code **echo $details[$_REQUEST['ImageID']];**, it still looks like that!

Why should this happen?

Comment: have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Probably cache issue, try clearing your cache or using igcognito mode

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded the new code. After a long session, I have been guilty of this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this for some time when I switched to a new server. You can use

```
opcache_reset();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php

I use that while coding in my dev environments on every php file.

When you first ad this to a php file it takes about five minutes for the cache to reset.

Comment: The cache resides server side, clearing a browser's cache will not correct the issue.